# Edit Jtable on Non-Focusable Window

Tags: java, swing, jtable, window

I have created my own WYSIWYG editor which consists of a design window and a tool palette window.
The design window is a JFrame and the tool palette is a JDialog with FocusableWindowState set to false.
However by switching the FocusableWindowState to false, I am no longer able to edit the cells in the JTable on my tool palette window. Changing it to true allows me to edit the cells.

Here is my code example:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setBounds(0, 0, 1024, 768);

JDialog paletteWindow = new JDialog(frame, false);
paletteWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
paletteWindow.setResizable(false);
paletteWindow.setFocusableWindowState(false);
paletteWindow.setBounds(1024, 0, 320, 768);

JTable grid = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new String[] {"Name", "Value"}, 5));
paletteWindow.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(grid));

frame.setVisible(true);
paletteWindow.setVisible(true);
```

How can I still edit the cells even if the FocusableWindowState is set to false?

Comment: Hi Cobus, please post your code relating to your question so we can help you.

Comment: See also [*How to Use Tool Bars*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html).

Comment: Tool Bars can create a float-able window but it still has a focusable window state and grabs the focus once you click on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question, although it might not conform to everyone's needs. I have used a KeyEventDispatcher to dispatch the key events from the focused frame to the editing cell editor. Here is my code example:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setBounds(0, 0, 1024, 768);

JDialog paletteWindow = new JDialog(frame, false);
paletteWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
paletteWindow.setResizable(false);
paletteWindow.setFocusableWindowState(false);
paletteWindow.setBounds(1024, 0, 320, 768);

JTable grid = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new String[] {"Name", "Value"}, 5)) {
    private KeyEventDispatcher dispatcher;

    @Override
    public Component getEditorComponent() {
        final Component c = super.getEditorComponent();
        if (dispatcher == null) {
            dispatcher = new KeyEventDispatcher() {
                public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
                    e.setSource(c);
                    for (KeyListener keyListener : c.getKeyListeners()) {
                        if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
                            keyListener.keyPressed(e);
                        } else if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
                            keyListener.keyReleased(e);
                        } else if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
                            keyListener.keyTyped(e);
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            };
            KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(dispatcher);
        }
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeEditor() {
        if (dispatcher != null) {
            KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().removeKeyEventDispatcher(dispatcher);
            dispatcher = null;
        }
        super.removeEditor();
    }
};
paletteWindow.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(grid));

frame.setVisible(true);
paletteWindow.setVisible(true);
```